# Trouble generating TopoJSON to use with D3's Choropleth example

Tags: javascript, d3.js, shapefile, topojson

So, I've been following this tutorial https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606. Just copying and pasting his code directly allows me to see this functionality in action. However, I would like to do the same thing but at the state scale rather than the whole country. So I went to the census bureau's website and downloaded a shapefile for the counties of Missoui, but I'm having difficulty recreating Mike's TopoJSON file. In fact, I've been at this for days, messing around with TopoJSON, but all of the examples I've found use the deprecated `topojson` command line tools. Since that doesn't exist anymore, I've been forced to figure out for myself how to generate in the same TopoJSON format, but with no luck. I simply cannot get a Shapefile into the same TopoJSON format that Mike uses in this tutorial.

So here is how I've been doing it. I'm getting my Shapefile from this website https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_counties.html and going to the Census 2000 tab (because I don't know how else to get only the counties for Missouri from this website) then selecting and downloading Missouri. I then unzip the downloaded file, then move the `.shp` and `.dbf` files to a separate folder. Then I run this command to produce the GeoJSON file:

```
shp2json c029_d00 -o missouri_geo.json
```

Then this command to make the TopoJSON file

```
geo2topo missouri_geo.json > missouri_topo.json
```

When I compare the format of my TopoJSON file to Mike's TopoJSON file, they are kind of similar, but there seems to be a bunch of missing formatting in my TopoJSON file. I understand that since my file is made from the Shapefile of just Missouri, that already there will be missing data, but I thought that my TopoJSON file would have attributes like the 'id' attribute that contains the FIPS codes for the counties, but my file does not have that. I want to figure out the process to convert a Shapefile into a TopoJSON file that can be used with Mike's code from his example, but I can't seem to figure it out.

*Note* my javascript and html code is exactly the same as Mike's in his example. In my TopoJSON file, I changed the line after `"objects":{` to `"counties"` to match with the line in the javascript code `us.objects.counties`. When I run my code and inspect it, I do not receive any errors, but nothing shows up. I do not see anything in my browser.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple potential challenges in replicating this map for a single state and it appears you have run into a few of them. You will need to deviate from the example more than you have.

---

First, the geographic data your are downloading is composed of latitude longitude pairs - the geographic data the example uses is a pre-projected topojson that is sized to fit in a 960x600 Cartesian plane. You will need to either pre-project your data as well (similar to [command line cartography part 1](https://medium.com/@mbostock/command-line-cartography-part-1-897aa8f8ca2c)) or project your data on the fly within your block using a geoPath and a geoProjection. Mike does use a geoProjection in his block, a null geoProjection, the default geoProjection for a geoPath. The null projection simply takes coordinates in the json and uses them as svg coordinates with no transform.

Projection issues are probably the most common cause of seeing neither features nor errors. Since you didn't specify a projection, the features are likely rendered off screen. As the continental US sits in the western hemisphere, longitude values are negative - the US will be drawn to the left of the origin, ie off the screen, since you are using a null projection.

---

The second potential issue for you is that your data has different attributes than the example:

> I thought that my TopoJSON file would have attributes like the 'id'
>   attribute that contains the FIPS codes for the counties

The feature attributes of your topojson:

```
"properties":{"AREA":0.140669542963654,
"PERIMETER":1.69104063251173,
"CO29_D00_":2,
"CO29_D00_I":1,
"STATE":"29",
"COUNTY":"045",
"NAME":"Clark",
"LSAD":"06",
"LSAD_TRANS":"County"}}
```

Are derived from the shapefile:

[image]

Since you are using a different source than Mike, the attributes of the data might be different. As the source doesn't have a FIPS ID you cannot make the join between your non-geographic data and your geographic features as in the example. However, there is a not too difficult solution:

- Create a FIPS code from the data you do have

From the NOAA (most succinct definition I found):

> The first two digits are for the State and the last three identify the County, or county equivalent. So, each State has its own 2-digit number, and each County within the state has its own 3-digit number, which are combined into a 5-digit number to uniquely identify every US county. ([source](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/mirs/public/prods/maps/cnty_fips_def.htm))

You have a number representing state and county - it's a safe bet that this is your FIPS county code when combined. You could combine them in making your geo/topojson, you could create a new property just before drawing the geojson features:

```
var features = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features;
features.forEach(function(d) {
   d.FIPS = "" + d.properties.STATE + d.properties.COUNTY;
})
```

or you could concatenate string and county when filling the feature:

```
.attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.rate = unemployment.get(
""+d.properties.STATE+d.properties.COUNTY)); })
```

[Here's](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/a0abd64c723b67b0e54e14176604ec91) what that might look like.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer this as thoroughly as you did. Obviously, I'm very new at this, so when I first attempted this a lot of the information I found on generating a geoProjection went over my head. But I think I'm starting to see how Mike used geoProjection to get the topoJSON just the way he wanted it.

Comment: I actually found the [command line cartography tutorial](https://medium.com/@mbostock/command-line-cartography-part-1-897aa8f8ca2c) shortly after I posted this question, and in it I found this [link](https://github.com/veltman/d3-stateplane/blob/master/README.md#nad83--illinois-east-epsg26971) which is the method I used for generating the geoProjection for Missouri. After generating the topoJSON file, and concatenating the string and county when filling the feature as you did, I am now able to see the unemployment data for Missouri successfully. Thank you so much, this was really helpful.

Comment: Glad to be able to help.